# Build failure with "no protocol: /api/v1/login" on build notification to RocketChat

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am using below code to send build notifications to `RocketChat` using `rocketSend`. Below is the code snippet:

```
rocketSend channel: 'jenkins-robot', "Build Notification - STATUS: ${currentBuild.result} - BRANCH: ${env.GERRIT_BRANCH} - PROJECT: ${env.PROJECT} - (<${env.BUILD_URL}|Open>)"
```

But I am getting below error:

```
[Pipeline] rocketSend
RocketChat Send Pipeline step configured with channel: jenkins-robot 
  message: Build Notification - STATUS: null - BRANCH: release-1.2 -  
  PROJECT: test - (<URL/|Open>)

 [Pipeline] }
 [Pipeline] // node
 [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
 java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /api/v1/login
```

I am not sure why I am getting `java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /api/v1/login` error.

Comment: Please indicate what you have tried so far, and the current issue you are facing.

Comment: I am getting below error
**java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /api/v1/login**
          ```
RocketChat Send Pipeline step configured with channel: jenkins-robot and message: Build Notification - STATUS: null - BRANCH: release-1.2 - PROJECT: fabric-sdk-node - (<https://jenkins.hyperledger.org/job/fabric-sdk-node-verify-s390x/52/|Open>)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /api/v1/login
       ```

Comment: This is my code

rocketSend channel: 'jenkins-robot', message: "Build Notification - STATUS: ${currentBuild.result} - BRANCH: ${env.GERRIT_BRANCH} - PROJECT: ${env.PROJECT} - (<${env.BUILD_URL}|Open>)"

Comment: Sure, in order for us to help you, you'll have to include **all** of the relevant code which produces that error, and it's best to do this by *editing your question and adding the code there* (properly formatted please!). That little section of code alone won't likely be enough.

Comment: Thanks @Shayn . I am unblocked now. Removed the Channel configuration from the rocketSend. Not sure why I am getting above error when I use channel confgiuration.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed with the below code: removed the "channel" information from rocketSend command

```
 rocketSend "Build Notification - STATUS: ${currentBuild.result} - BRANCH: ${env.GERRIT_BRANCH} - PROJECT: ${env.PROJECT} - BUILD_URL: (<${env.BUILD_URL}|Open>)"
```